# Spark avro insertInto file extension

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I've an external Hive table based on Avro.

```
| CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `temp_avro`(                 |
|   `string1` string COMMENT '')                     |
| PARTITIONED BY (                                   |
|   `string2` string)                                |
| ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'   |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'  |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                       |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat' |
| LOCATION                                           |
|   'hdfs://xxx/xxx/temp_avro' |
| TBLPROPERTIES (                                    |
|   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1503938718')            |
```

I'm trying to write to this table using Spark as:

```
SELECT_0_0.toDF().write.mode("append").insertInto("temp_avro")
```

With this, the avro file gets created in the HDFS location without avro extension (with names part-00001, part-00002, and so on). Is there a way to have the file name with extension .avro

Comment: What is your motivation for that?

Comment: The application that is consuming this data expecting to have a .avro extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try using coalesce to reduce parts combining to one before saving your results

```
SELECT_0_0.toDF().coalesce(1).write.mode("append").insertInto("temp_avro")
```